# What does the -st word ending mean and is it used in any modern vocabulary?

Tags: meaning, verbs, suffixes

I know there are plenty of words that use the -st ending: wouldst, whilst, unbeknownst, etc. but I'm not really sure what it means to add an -st suffix to a word. What does it mean to add the suffix? How can I tell what words can take the -st suffix? Are there any modern words that can take the suffix and not have people look at me in a strange way?

Comment: For *whilst, amongst, amidst*, it's a remnant of archaic English grammar that I don't understand ... I hope somebody will give a good explanation in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *-st* endings are two different grammatical animals. In *wouldst* it is the standard verb ending for the archaic second person singular familiar *thou*:

> *Cleopatra*. O, I would thou *didst*, 
>   So half my Egypt were submerged and made
>   A cistern for scaled snakes! Go, get thee hence: 
>   *Hadst* thou Narcissus in thy face, to me 
>   Thou [*wouldst*](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=antonycleo&Act=2&Scene=5&Scope=scene) appear most ugly. He is married? — *Antony and Cleopatra* 2.5.1174–8.

*Unbeknownst*, however, is another creature entirely, even among its peers.

Emerging in both British and North American print sources in the 1830’s,  *unbeknownst* was originally a colloquialism coined on the pattern of much older words such as [*unawares*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/unawares#etymonline_v_24906) (1530s) or [*always*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/always#etymonline_v_10936) (early 13th c.), adding the etymologically intrusive final *t* of *amongst, whilst, betwixt*, etc. The *s* is a remnant of the genitive case, often used in Old and Middle English to form adverbs from nouns or adjectives.

> I think that 'ere Ingian must have been the devil, or how could he come so sudden and [*unbeknownst*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=aeu.ark:/13960/t08w46x67;view=1up;seq=14) upon me, … John Richardson,  *Wacousta, or, The Prophecy: A Tale of the Canadas*, London, 1832.
>
> “I remember my respectable first-floor, Monsieur Boncoeur, bringing home a piping bullfinch last year he’d bought on the Boulevards, whose red breast washed off the first showery day, all as one as Ma’mselle Isoline’s rouge after a flood of tears in a melodrame! The poor dear gentleman had half a mind to have up the seller of the impositious bird before the commissary of the district; only, as he’d paid for it with an old coat [*unbeknownst*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044092636364;view=1up;seq=541) to his valet, and an old coat not being lawful coin of the realm, there was a doubt in his mind about his power of bringing the vagabond to justice.” — Toby Allspy (pseud.), “Adventures in Paris: The Five Floors,” *Bentley’s Miscellany* 2 (1837), 501.
>
> “No matter,” added Lynx authoritatively ;  “getting into another man’s barrel [*unbeknownst*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc2.ark:/13960/t12n51q0z;view=1up;seq=232) to him in the night-time, is burglary.” — Joseph C. Neal, *Charcoal Sketches; or, Scenes in a Metropolis*, Philadelphia, 1839.

The word also appears in an 1875 Sussex dialect dictionary, suggesting the usage is older than its first appearance in print:

> **Unbeknownst**. Unknown.
>   “All I can say is, if he comes here, it's quite [*unbeknownst*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hx57sa;view=1up;seq=143) to me.” — William Douglas Parish, *A Dictionary of the Sussex Dialect and Collection of Provincialisms*, Lewes, 1875, 127

Even so, the word is a likely candidate for the last coinage in English using the adverbial genitive.

The [adverbial genitive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_genitive), though no longer productive, is a feature especially common to West Germanic languages. It’s hiding in plain sight in many common English words: *once, twice, sideways, backwards, forwards* and the alternatives *amongst, whilst* more common to British usage.

This means that you can no longer form words using the adverbial genitive *-s*, and unless you’re in a Shakespearean play, you won’t be using the *thou* form of English verbs anytime soon.

Comment: Wow, 5 years later this answer is absolutely is the best. Thank you for taking the time to answer and old question of mine.

Answer (score 15):

Long long ago in a galaxy far far away...uh, well, not really.

English used to have a more complex grammar than it does presently.  It is a Germanic tongue and so retains a touch of German in old, not so much used, forms.

The -st you refer to are from the old second person singular.  Wouldst:

- Wouldst = Wouldest thou - would you
- Wouldest thou that I could = Wouldst that I could = would that I could

While "wouldst" is uncommmon, I have heard "unbeknownst" used much more commonly: "Unbeknownst to me, she was married."  This would likely not sound odd at all to me, just perhaps a touch formal.

Another one that is completely disused is "durst", which is the second person singular of "to dare".

**ETA:** Originally, I had included a couple of paragraphs about "whilst" as a verb, but a comment by @siride (that I didn't examine closely until a year after posting this answer) clued me into the fact that I was wrong about "whilst".  I refer you to the comments below for more data on that.

Comment: The odd thing about this one is that [*Americans have enthusiastically taken up the archaic form **unbeknownst** in recent decades*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unbeknownst%2Cunbeknown&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=), despite the fact that they clearly have [*no time for **whilst***](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whilst%2Cwhile&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). Thou ***wouldst*** hardly have expected Americans to be leading the field in terms of reviving archaic forms! :)

Comment: "While we watch Rugby, the Americans watch Football.": A Brit would say "Americans watch _American_ football", as "football" in BrE = "soccer" in AmE. :-)

Comment: Yes, you're more correct than I was.

Comment: "whilst" has nothing to do with the 2nd person singular as it clearly isn't a verb. It's in the same group as "amongst" and "amidst", where the "t" was added to a form already ending in "s" to achieve some sort of euphony (German has done similar things: "niemand", "jetzt", etc.)

Comment: @siride, that's a good point, however there actually *IS* a verb "to while", and that's what I was thinking of. Perhaps I was incorrect in associating it with this question.  "To while away" = *to pass time idly*.  Hmmm.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: yes, there is such a verb, but that's not the origin of "whilst" as a conjunction. It is possible for verbs to fill that role, but we have a much more acceptable explanation and evidence to back it up, so if we intend to be scientific, it's best not to go with fantastical explanations.

Comment: See also: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=while&allowed_in_frame=0.

Comment: Thanks, @siride, for that link. As an aside, I love being scientific but sometimes I like to go for the fantastical instead, for a change of pace! But perhaps this is not the proper forum for it! :-)  This means of course that I have eviscerate my answer!  Oh, the pain.

Comment: Sorry to take away another bit, but _durst_ isn't the second singular of _dare_. It's just the old preterite form. The verb itself actually has (or had) a root _dVrs-_ (V = vowel liable to change by ablaut), but _rs_ became _rr_ intervocalically in OE, yielding _dare_ instead of something like _*darse_. It was an old preterite-present in OE, meaning it formed its preterite by o-grade + d-suffix, like _sceal_ (shall) > _sceol-de_ (should): _dearr_ (dare) > _dors-te_ (durst).

Comment: FWIW, @JanusBahsJacquet, I've seen *durst* used that way. Perhaps the usage was incorrect.  Or it may have been a regional form of *darest*: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/darest

Comment: It could be either—or just a mixing up of both. _Thou durst_ could be a blend of _thou darest_ and _thou durstest_, easy enough to get mixed up if you're not hot on your ME conjugations. (And note Yorkshire forms like _durs(t)n’t_, which are from the preterite, but are used as both present and past forms.)

Answer (score 2):

For unbeknown vs. unbeknownst: http://fandom-grammar.livejournal.com/39346.html
which would probably explain the others also. "Whilst" I've heard British people use working with them, but everything they say sounds funny and lovely!

Comment: I lived there for a few years, once upon a time, and I agree that "everything they say sounds funny and lovely!"  Although it is not so much *what* they say, but *how* they say it!